# How to filter results inclusively (AND) with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have two models: `Worker` and `Skill`.
A worker can have multiple skills. Each skill has its own name (e.g. 'php', 'web-development' etc.)

In my search form I want to be able to filter workers (with the help of **searchkick**) according to their skills. If multiple skills are selected in the form, the search results should only include those workers, who have **all** the skills which have been selected.

---

I tried the following:

**worker.rb**

```
has_many :worker_skills
has_many :skills, through: worker_skills

searchkick
scope :search_import, -> { includes(:skills) }

def search_data
  {
    skills_name: skills.pluck(:name)
  }
end
```

**skill.rb**

```
has_many :worker_skills
has_many :workers, through: :worker_skills
```

**workers_controller.rb**

```
def index
  ...
  @workers = Worker.search(
    params[:q],
    where: {
      skills_name: params[:skills]
    }
  end
  ...
end
```

This returns me all the workers who have at least one of the selected skills.

**Example:**

```
Filters selected: ['php', 'ruby']
```

```
Result: All workers who either have 'php' - OR - 'ruby' as a skill.
```

---

How can I achieve it to only return those workers who have both skills at the same time?
i.e. 'php' - AND - 'ruby'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look here https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying you can use the `all` parameter so that it must match with all elements in the where clause. Do the following in your **workers_controller.rb**:

```
def index
  ...
  @workers = Worker.search(
    params[:q],
    where: {
      skills_name: {
        all: params[:skills]
      }
    }
  end
  ...
end
```

Also keep in mind to ensure that you have values in `params[:skills]`. If not you get an **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** Error. So maybe disable the search button until some values were selected.